# How to make a char express a string?

Tags: java

First and foremost, forgive me for my english. It's my third language so explaining what's in my head will be difficult.

```
System.out.println("quelle sorte de pizza désirez-vous ? [V]egetarienne, [F]romage,[T]oute Garnie,[E]pinards, Fruits de [M]er");
       sortePizza = Clavier.lireCharLn();
```

"           sortePizza = Clavier.lireCharLn(); " 
This is the equivalent of scanner in our school, theyre using "clavier(keyboard)" as the method of input. (just for this session)

I'm doing a program that is supposed to bill a client who wants to order from a pizza store. When he will chose, lets say "V" (Char) for vegetarian, I would like to see on the bill that he ordered a Vegetarian (String) using the "V" char..

I hope I made myself clear enough, i'm so sorry for my english lol im doing my best

Comment: An important piece of information is what the return type of `lireCharLn()` is.

Comment: it's the keyboard that reads the char input

Comment: That's not what I'm asking; you're telling me the source of the information. I'm asking the *return type* of the method. In the `Clavier` class, there's a method defined as `public **** lireCharLn()`, and we need to know what that type is.

Comment: @chrylis i have no idea what youre talking about :(

Comment: @chrylis It seems like it returns either a `char` or a `Character`.

Comment: Based on some Googling around, I think it's a `char`.  I.e. `char sortePizza;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your program returned char (character) to you, and you put it in a char variable, which you named `sortePizza` I think you have some options.

You can use some if-statements for each choice:

```
    if(sortePizza == 'V'){
      //Ajoute la pizza vegetarienne sur la note
    } else if (sortePizza == 'T'){
     // ajoute "toute garnie" et le prix sur la note
    } //… ainsi de suite pour toute les options
      else {
      System.out.println("Wrong input message");
      //au cas ou quelqu'un type something not correct
      }
```

You could do the same with a switch statement...(look for it in the comment right below mine)
Or you could try to use a Map of char and strings. Please see (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

But I think you could simply do it with some if statements.

Answer (score 1):

Look into maps. You want a `Character` to map to a `String`, like so:

```
Map<Character, String> pizzaTypes = new HashMap<>;
pizzaTypes.put('v', "Vegetarienne");
...
pizzaTypes.put('m', "Fruits de Mer");
```

To use the map, convert user input to lowercase and just look it up:

```
String result = pizzaTypes.get(Character.toLowerCase(sortePizza));
if(result == null) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
} else {
    System.out.println("You ordered a " + result + " pizza");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking. Would a possible solution be using something as simple as a switch statement on the input char.
So something like:

```
switch (sortePizza) {
    case 'V': // Let the statement below handle this case.
    case 'v': // Do whatever you want with it here.
              // For example you could add to a string that represents the bill.
             break;
    default: // Add in default behaviour.
             break;
}
```

Is that what you're aiming to do? You could also use an if statement for the inputs instead of a switch statement.